# Explicit expression for a periodic function with repeated lines.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know there HAS to be a better way to describe the function I'm looking for, but I'm looking for an explicit form for the following function with domain $(0,4)$:

$$f(x)=  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      x & 0\leq x\leq 1 \\
      2-x & 1< x\leq 3 \\
x-4 & 3<x\leq 4
\end{array} 
\right. $$
Tile this function with period $4$ over $(0,4),(4,8),...$

Essentially, it's just a spiky wave function. I would like an explicit form of this including floor functions, maybe something of the form $\max \{f(x),g(x)\},$ I have no idea. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [0,4] :
$$
f : x\to \min(\max(0, x), 1) + \min(0, 1 - x) + 2\max(0, x - 3)
$$
By defining
$$
g:x\to f\left(x-4\text{floor}\left(\frac x4\right)\right)
$$
you get your periodic function

Answer (score 1):

I found two ways of making an explicit continuous periodic function.

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{2\arcsin{\left(\sin{\left(\frac{x\pi}{2}\right)}\right)}}{\pi}$$

Which works fine for programs like Desmos, despite the $\arcsin(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ cancelling out in general math. This still works because $\arcsin{x}$ is the principle branch. If you need something that doesn't require using a principle branch, I suggest something like this:

$$f\left(x\right)=-\mathrm{sign}\left((x-1)\bmod 4\right)\left(2-\left((x-1)\bmod 4\right)\right)-1$$

This one works works without the need of a principle branch.